# Using if and controlling numbers in ksh

Tags: ksh

I would like to download file with the format cars000.txt, cars003.txt,cars006.txt, till cars105.txt...interval of 3 as you can see

I use the following code in ksh, but after downloading cars012.txt, it fails, it begins to download cars13.txt,...and I don't wish it. What does it fails in the code?

```
FHR=000
while [ $FHR -le 105 ]
do
file=cars${FHR}.txt

wget http://${dir_target}/${file}
(( FHR = $FHR + 03 ))
echo $FHR

if [[ $FHR -le 10 ]]; then FHR="00"$FHR
else FHR="0"$FHR
fi

done
```

Answer (score 1):

You should decide: is FHR a string, a decimal or an octal.
You are mixing them currently.
Try the next improvement:

```
FHR=0
while [ ${FHR} -le 105 ]; do
   file=cars${FHR}.txt

   (( FHR = FHR + 3 ))
   echo Without leading zero: FHR=${FHR}

   if [[ $FHR -le 10 ]]; then
      echo "FHR=00${FHR}"
   else
      echo "FHR=0${FHR}"
   fi
   sleep 1
done
```

(The next improvement might be using printf or awk and no zero for 102/105)